# Error when mapping dictionary values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to map some values from a dictionary to a dataframe. There is a column in the dataframe titled month where the values are from 1-12. My dictionary equates the numeric month value to its name, e.g. 1: January...

When I try in the code below I get NaN's and am not sure why.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7iqm.jpg)

```
month_dict = {"1" : "January", "2" : "February", "3" : "March", "4" : "April", "5" : "May" , "6" : "June", "7" : "July", "8" : "August", "9" : "September", "10" : "October" ,"11" : "November","12" : "December"}

df['month'] = df['month'].map(month_dict)
```

I expect to have the month names substituted for the numerical equivalents but only return NaN's. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need same type of data in column and in keys of dictionary.

---

Solution for matching strings:

Cast column to strings, because strings in keys in dictionary:

```
month_dict = {"1" : "January", "2" : "February", "3" : "March", "4" : "April", 
              "5" : "May" , "6" : "June", "7" : "July", "8" : "August", 
              "9" : "September", "10" : "October" ,"11" : "November","12" : "December"}

df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str).map(month_dict)
```

---

Solution for matching integers:

Convert keys in dictionary to integers:

```
month_dict = {int(k):v for k, v in month_dict.items()}
print (month_dict)
{1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 
 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}

df['month'] = df['month'].map(month_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! Could you explain this line of code you have put:    
month_dict = {int(k):v for k, v in month_dict.items()}
print (month_dict) is 'k' the integer value I have assigned to each month? Is this code stating only k is an integer or both k and v?

Comment: @AndrewAndreas - It is called [`dictionary comprehension`](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) and simply loop each key:value of dictionary with converting keys to integers - output is another dictionary. If your question was answered, please accept answer by clicking the grey check to the left of that answer to toggle it green. It helps the community. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry was not aware of the grey tick but have done it now. Thanks again for the help! Really appreciate it